# What is the phrase describing "insects causing trouble and anxiety repeatly"?

Tags: phrase-request

> He has to fight with a lot of insects around his house in every summer, which have caused repeated trouble and anxiety to him.

Could I call them *haunting insects* indicating the effect they are bringing? If not, what's the appropriate phrase?

Comment: "Haunting insects" doesn't describe "insects repeatedly causing anxiety." Somebody could get anxious by hearing crickets.

Comment: Please stop fighting with insects.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another word that fits in context is ***pesky***.

*Pesky*, however, do only conveys the meaning of being annoying or making you feel upset. I don't know any word that has the additional connotation of becoming anxious because of something what is bothering you. For that reason, I'd phrase it like that.

> He's worrying about pesky insects.

Aside: On COCA *pesky* is the second collocation (11 usages) with *insects* which partially conveys the idea you're looking for. The first is *annoying* (16 usages). On BNC the first word which matches is *offending* (only 2 usages).

Words like *stitching*, *biting*, *harmful*, *poisonous* etc. may incidentally convey that insects will likely be annoying or worrying but their meaning doesn't include that sense at hand.

Comment: I would rather say that something poisonous worries me, not that it annoys me.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Agreed. But that wasn't my point. I just was saying that a lot of words (some of them I mentioned) make it rather superfluous to add the idea of something being annoying, worrying or whatever, i.e. using such a word implies the idea of “insects causing trouble and anxiety repeatly” as written in OP's title.

Answer (score 4):

I would rather call them "bothersome/bothering insects" or "annoying insects".

Comment: "Bothersome" is another alternative, probably used more often than "bothering".

Comment: @barbarabeeton: added this to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Flies, mosquitos, & similar insects that keep buzzing around your house and refusing to go away or be caught are **pesky insects**.

A large number of fleas, bedbugs, ants, or other insects that are ruining things in your home is an **infestation**.

A colony of termites that is causing structural damage to your home is a **disaster**.